# Using ANOVA to analyse likert scale data

Tags: anova, likert

I need to analyze this hypothesis
h0:Men use cell phone for calls more than woman do.
Made a quesstionaire and asked on the likert scale

How often do you use your cell phone for calls

1=hourly
2=at least once per day
3=at least once every few days
4=once a week
5=never used

Can i analyse the data using one way ANOVA by making phone call dependent variable and gender:male/female as independent variable.
What other method can i use.Thanks.

Comment: 1. Are you sure that hypothesis isn't the alternative (H1)? It doesn't contain an equality. 2. Either way the questionnaire does not deal with the stated hypothesis. One hypothesis that would correspond to the questionnaire would (in words) be "Men report using cell phones for calls more than ... " (etc). To test the hypothesis you mentioned would require measuring whether men actually do that, not that they say they do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I want to know who uses cell phones for call more men or women.So ill  make it a research question rather than hypothesis.Can you ans my question regarding the analysis that can i use anova for it even though i have likert scale type data

Comment: Anova is not a good choice. How many participants in total, and what is the range of counts per response for each group ?

Comment: I don't think you can call this a Likert scale, as this is just one item. In fact it is simply a dependent categorical variable with 5 values, with an independent variable that is dichotomous. You would need a categorical-with-categorical association measure, strictly speaking. In social sciences, it would be a widespread (though incorrect, statistically speaking) practice to treat your dependent as continuous. Then you could use ANOVA, but I'd recommend against that, as more appropriate methods exist. Odds ratios could be used as well. A Chi-square test of independence too, I imagine.

Comment: 400  participants                                                                                      380 male     80 female

Comment: I am collecting data through google forms .When i import the csv file into spss the gender section has string data type "male and "female" i want to convert into numerical data 1 and 2 . how can i do that .thanks

Answer (score 1):

First off, as others pointed out, $H_0$ should be that there is no difference.

Next you don't need ANOVA as you have only two groups, which would be a t test. However you cannot do a t-test because the scale is categorical.

One possibility is to convert your answers from 1,2,3,4,5 to "times per week" so then 
1 = 70 (or something)
2 = 7
3 = 2
4 = 1
5 = 0

then you could do a t-test, but I don't recommend this here as your categories are pretty poorly chosen.

I'd say you want some ordinal test that does not assume equal spacing.  One such is the Jonckheere-Terpstra test. In SAS, it is available in PROC FREQ with the JT option.  In R it is in the clinfun package.